# About the best way to use savepoint in EF

Tags: c#, orm

```
App.Current.RunWithUow(() =>
{
    var uow = App.GetCurrentUOW();

    string savePoint = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");

    var repo01 = uow.GetRepository(table01);
    var repo02 = uow.GetRepository(table02);
    var repo03 = uow.GetRepository(table03);

    uow.Save(savePoint);

    try
    {
        repo01.Add(……);
        // uow.SaveChanges();
        repo02.Add(……);
        // uow.SaveChanges();
        repo03.Add(……); // exception here

        uow.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        uow.Rollback(savePoint);
    }
}
); // auto saveChanges and commit();


-- Rollback method, auto saveChanges again.
Rollback(string savePoint)
{
    uow.SaveChanges();
    uow.DbTransaction.Rollback(savePoint);
}
```

Question:

The above is a sample code. I don't want developers to use savechange everywhere.

Therefore, in the above scenario, a piece of business code may need to operate three tables. When operating the third table, an exception occurs, and I need to roll back to the savepoint. Therefore, when I roll back to a savepoint, I call saveChanges again.

I wonder if this is reasonable.

Thank you

Comment: From Microsoft doc about EF: "In all versions of Entity Framework, whenever you execute SaveChanges() to insert, update or delete on the database the framework will wrap that operation in a transaction. " . So I don't see the point of your transactions here with rollback.

Comment: Inside the runuow method, I will start the database transaction. Therefore, saveChanges will not actually commit to the database. I will call the commit method of database transactions at the end of the runuow method

Comment: Ef6 does not support savepoint. I have extended it myself